# C# String to float with f

Tags: c#, string, parsing, unity-game-engine

BTW: the xposs is recieved from a server so i cant just say its a float, i need it converted to a float with 0.0f behind:

```
xposs = "951.9791"

xspawn = float.Parse(yposs);
```

this just returns 951.9791 in a float but i want 951.9791f

i have also tried:

```
xposs = "951.9791"

xspawn = float.Parse(yposs) + 0.0f;
```

this still does not work.

I need it to be 0.0f format becaouse i use it in a Vector3(), and not having the f does not seem to work (well it works but the cordinates are totally wrong, and if i manually press f after it works.)

Comment: My guess is there is something else wrong...perhaps you are not getting the values from your server that you think you are?

Comment: perhaps you're not account for floating point rounding errors.

Comment: For use in a `Vector3` or whatever, your `xspawn` should be good as it is! The extra `f` is not in the usual string representation of a `float`. If you really needed to have a value followed by an `f` in some variable, you could use a string, and it could be constructed like `string xspawnStrWithF = xspawn + "f";`, but it is not what you need.

Comment: The Unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 7):

`f` postfix is applied only to literals in code. It is used to denote literal values as `float`. If no postfix is present - literal value will be of type `double`

you can pass the result of `float.Parse(stringValue)` into `Vector3` and `Vector2` as constructor arguments in Unity 3d
The next code create a Vector3 object with x y z equal to value set in string

```
string sideSize = "12.5";
float vectorSide = float.Parse(sideSize, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Vector3 resultVector = new Vector3(vectorSide, vectorSide, vectorSide); //create vector3 with x = y = z = 12.5
```

Answer (score 6):

the "f" suffix is supplied in literal values to denote the data type

- f for float
- m for decimal
- d for double

Answer (score 3):

Floats are just a numeric value with type `System.Single`. They don't have an `f` behind it. That's just the notation C# uses for `float` literals. `float.Parse` returns a `float`, it's not possible or necessary to add an `f`.

Comment: That's `System.Single`, actually, not `System.Float`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - System.Float does not exist. float is an alias for System.Single in the same way that long is an alias for System.Int64 - see [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b1e65aza(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Darren Jeppe was correcting a mistake in an earlier version of my post. I keep forgetting that it's `System.Single` not `System.Float`.